# How to calculate vectors with word2vec

Tags: gensim

Assume I have a number of pictures. Let’s say 10 pictures which are annotated by 50 people each.
So Pic 1 might be „beach, vacation, relax, sand, sun…“ I now trained word2vec with a domain specific content. I have the vectors of each word and can represent them. But what I want now, is to create ONE final vector representing each picture. So one vector with represents the 50 annotations (beach, vacation, relax, sand, sun…)

Let’s assume each vector is represented with 100 dimensions – do I just add the first dimension (the 100 dimensions) of all 50 vectors, than the 2nd dimension of all 50 vectors… etc.

I am very thankful for any comments that might help me!

I tried this, but I am not sure if this is the right way to do it. 
I also tried doc2vec but I guess this is problematic as the word order of the annotations is irrelevant – but relevant for doc2vec.???

Answer (score 0):

A few thoughts:

A list of annotations isn't *quite* like natural-language narrative text – in either the relative frequencies of tokens, or the importance of neighboring-tokens. So you may want to try out a extra-wide range of training parameters. For example, using a giant `window` (far larger than each of your texts) could essentially negate the (possibly-arbitrary) ordering of the annotations, putting every word in every other word's context. (That'd increase training time, but might help in other ways.) Also, look into the newly-tunable `ns_exponent` parameter - the paper referenced from the [gensim docs](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/word2vec.html#gensim.models.word2vec.Word2Vec) suggests values very different from the default may help in certain recommendation contexts.

That said, the most-simple way to combine many vectors into one is to average them all together. Whether that works well for your purposes, you'd have to test. (It unavoidably loses the information of a larger set of independent vectors, but if other aspects of your modeling are strong enough – enough training data, enough dimensions – the really important shared aspects may be retained in the summary vector.)

(You can see some code for averaging word-vectors in another [recent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57125306/valueerror-cannot-reshape-array-of-size-3800-into-shape-1-200/57150751#57150751).)

You could also try `Doc2Vec`. It is no more ordering-dependent than `Word2Vec` – some modes use a `window`-sized context where neighboring words influence each other. (But other modes don't, or, as mentioned above, an oversized `window` can essentially make neighboring-distances less-relevant).

Comment: It took quite a while until things are running. However thank you - everything worked out! I finally used Doc2Vec which worked awesomely.