# ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 3800 into shape (1,200)

Tags: python, deep-learning, tokenize, word2vec, word-embedding

I am trying to apply word embedding on tweets. I was trying to create a vector for each tweet by taking the average of the vectors of the words present in the tweet as follow:

```
def word_vector(tokens, size):
    vec = np.zeros(size).reshape((1, size))
    count = 0.
    for word in tokens:
        try:
            vec += model_w2v[word].reshape((1, size))
            count += 1.
        except KeyError: # handling the case where the token is not in vocabulary

            continue
    if count != 0:
        vec /= count
    return vec
```

Next, when I try to Prepare word2vec feature set as follow:

```
wordvec_arrays = np.zeros((len(tokenized_tweet), 200))
#the length of the vector is 200

for i in range(len(tokenized_tweet)):
    wordvec_arrays[i,:] = word_vector(tokenized_tweet[i], 200)

wordvec_df = pd.DataFrame(wordvec_arrays)
wordvec_df.shape
```

I get the following error inside the loop:

> ```
> ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
> <ipython-input-32-72aee891e885> in <module>
>       4 # wordvec_arrays.reshape(1,200)
>       5 for i in range(len(tokenized_tweet)):
> ----> 6     wordvec_arrays[i,:] = word_vector(tokenized_tweet[i], 200)
>       7 
>       8 wordvec_df = pd.DataFrame(wordvec_arrays)
>
> <ipython-input-31-9e6501810162> in word_vector(tokens, size)
>       4     for word in tokens:
>       5         try:
> ----> 6             vec += model_w2v.wv.__getitem__(word).reshape((1, size))
>       7             count += 1.
>       8         except KeyError: # handling the case where the token is not in vocabulary
>
> ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 3800 into shape (1,200)
> ```

I checked all the available posts in stackOverflow but non of them really helped me.

I tried reshaping the array and it still give me the same error.

My model is:

```
tokenized_tweet = df['tweet'].apply(lambda x: x.split()) # tokenizing

model_w2v = gensim.models.Word2Vec(
            tokenized_tweet,
            size=200, # desired no. of features/independent variables 
            window=5, # context window size
            min_count=2,
            sg = 1, # 1 for skip-gram model
            hs = 0,
            negative = 10, # for negative sampling
            workers= 2, # no.of cores
            seed = 34)

model_w2v.train(tokenized_tweet, total_examples= len(df['tweet']), epochs=20)
```

any suggestions please?

Comment: If you add the full exception message (all frames & lines), it will be clearer which line is causing the exception. But also, you may ind it easier to calculate the mean-of-many-word-vectors by modeling your code after the way it's done inside the `gensim` `KeyedVectors` classes. For example, the `n_similarity()` method averages-the-vectors for two sets-of-words in this line of code: https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/f97d0e793faa57877a2bbedc15c287835463eaa9/gensim/models/keyedvectors.py#L996

Comment: I added the full exception message.

Comment: Thanks for the extra details! Stlll, I'd suggest adopting a more-simple approach modeled after the example code I linked. Adding an answer with more details now..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the intent of your `word_vector()` method is to take a list of words, and then with respect to a given `Word2Vec` model, return the average of all those words' vectors (when present).

To do that, you shouldn't need to do any explicit re-shaping of vectors – or even specification of `size`, because that's forced by what the model already provides. You could use utility methods from `numpy` to simplify the code a lot. For example, the `gensim` `n_similarity()` method, as part of its comparision of **two** lists-of-words, already does an averaging much like what you're trying, and you can look at its source as a model:

https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/f97d0e793faa57877a2bbedc15c287835463eaa9/gensim/models/keyedvectors.py#L996

So, while I haven't tested this code, I think your `word_vector()` method could be essentially replaced with:

```
import numpy as np

def average_words_vectors(tokens, wv_model):
    vectors = [wv_model[word] for word in tokens 
               if word in wv_model]  # avoiding KeyError
    return np.array(vectors).mean(axis=0)
```

(It's sometimes the case that it makes sense to work with vectors that have been normalized to unit-length - as the linked `gensim` code via applying `gensim.matutils.unitvec()` to the average. I haven't done this here, as your method hadn't taken that step – but it is something to consider.)

Separate observations about your `Word2Vec` training code:

- typically words with just 1, 2, or a few occurrences **don't** get good vectors (due to limited number & variety of examples), but **do interfere** with the improvement of other more-common-word vectors. That's why the default is `min_count=5`. So just be aware: your surviving vectors may get better if you use a default (or even larger) value here, discarding more of the rarer words.
- the dimensions of a "dense embedding" like word2vec-vectors aren't really "independent variables" (or standalone individually-interpretable "features") as implied by your code-comment, even though they may seem that way as separate values/slots in the data. For example, you can't pick one dimension out and conclude, "that's the foo-ness of this sample" (like 'coldness' or 'hardness' or 'positiveness' etc). Rather, any of those human-describable meanings tend to be other directions in the combined-space, not perfectly aligned with any of the individual dimensions. You can sort-of tease those out by comparing vectors, and downstream ML algorithms can make use of those complicated/entangled multi-dimensional interactions. But if you think of each dimensions as its own "feature" – in any way other than yes, it's technically a single number associated with the item – you may be prone to misinterpreting the vector-space.